# Can Zend Optimizer and IonCube co-reside on the same server?

Tags: php, php-5.2, ioncube, zend-optimizer

We have a Windows 2008 server that already has Zend Optimizer installed but have been asked by a user if we can install IonCube?

Can Zend Optimizer and IonCube co-reside on the same server?

What are the correct directives to use to make this work in the `php.ini` file?

We're running PHP 5.2.14 non-threadsafe build.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Zend Optimizer and IonCube can co-reside on the same server:

> **[Q. Can I install Zend Optimizer with  the Loader?](http://www.ioncube.com/faq.php?sid=1d442d702d1781b4639c7c566b801878&sid=1d442d702d1781b4639c7c566b801878#zo2)**
>
> A. Yes. We permit trusted
> software to be installed, and so we
> support the installing of Zend
> Optimizer along with our Loader in the
> php.ini file.
>
> **Note that our Loader must be installed before Zend Optimizer in the php.ini file.**
>
> If you
> do see messages claiming any
> incompatibility then this is incorrect
> and will be a configuration problem.
> Please let us know and we'll let you
> know what's wrong.

Comment: Somehow my google searches missed that one. So what would be the correct directives to put in the php.ini file to make this work? I am hopelessly lost here.

Comment: Why the downvote? That last paragraph sounds *damn* cheeky, but that's not the answerer's fault.

Comment: @pekka - See 1st rev of answer.

Comment: @Kev ah, I see. That would piss me off too. Still, consider taking away the downvote anyway - because at the end of the day, he *did* answer your question. As to the Google comment, @hopeseekr, this is not how things work on SO. See e.g. discussion in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/33376/is-it-bad-to-ask-google-searchable-questions-on-stack-overflow... Don't be a dick.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't being snide! I was genuinely thanking the guy for giving me such an easy question to answer!!  However, I can surely delete this answer, if it makes you feel better.

Comment: um...zend_extension=/path/to/ioncube_encoder.so (new line) zend_extension=/path/to/zendoptimizer.so.  If you need help w/ PHP.ini, just make a new question.

Comment: @hopeseekr - no don't delete. Sorry if I took it the wrong way, but it's just the way it looked. We try and keep our questions answers to the point and lmgtfy type answers and the like are frowned upon.